# Launchpad fails to show app icons contained in folders

Tags: macos, launchpad

Randomly, my Launchpad is failing to show app icons contained in folders.

[image]

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Until now resetting the Launchpad database worked for me. Try:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

Note that this operation will reset the organisation of your Launchpad back to default.

Comment: Ok, maybe it works, but is it possible to avoid having to set up the launchpad again from scratch?

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to simply quickly open and close Launchpad back and forth (I used the four finger closing gesture on the trackpad to accomplish this) until the icons in folders show up.