# Launchpad folders showing icons within as blank squares with dashed lines

Tags: dock, macos, launchpad

There's a peculiar thing happening in my launchpad. On opening it up anytime in general, all the folders show no icons in them but blank squares drawn using dashed lines, the icons don't come back even if I wait a while. If I go inside a folder, the icons are there. If I close launchpad right away and reopen it again immediately, the icons are there. I am almost certain this started after upgrading to Sierra.

Of course, if I do `killall Dock`, it works but only until I reboot/logout. The other thing [advised](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/01/refresh-launchpad-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/) to do in this case is to remove the `.db` files in `~/Library/Application Support/Dock` but that location is empty on my machine.

This isn't at all a showstopper, but is certainly very odd, and I would like to do something about it, if there's something reasonable that can be done about it, as a long-term/permanent fix.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I once had the same problem, but interestingly it was *resolved* by rebooting.

Comment: There seems to be a solution [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256122/launchpad-failed-to-show-app-icons-contained-into-folders), but I'd like to do that without having to reorganise my launchpad from scratch.

Comment: I now believe this is caused by being the machine being low on memory(RAM). So for anyone else facing this: check your memory usage at the time of this problem.